# Jenkins v2.212: Error creating extended parser class: Class not found

Tags: jenkins

After upgrading Jenkins to v2.212, and installing many plugin updates available, some Jobs start failing with the following error:

```
12:43:35 [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
12:43:35 [WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
12:43:35 FATAL: Error creating extended parser class: Class not found
12:43:35 java.io.IOException: Class not found
12:43:35    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
12:43:35    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
12:43:35    at org.parboiled.transform.AsmUtils.createClassReader(AsmUtils.java:56)
12:43:35    at org.parboiled.transform.ClassNodeInitializer.process(ClassNodeInitializer.java:62)
12:43:35    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.extendParserClass(ParserTransformer.java:44)
12:43:35    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.transformParser(ParserTransformer.java:39)
12:43:35    at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:54)
12:43:35 Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating extended parser class: Class not found
12:43:35    at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:58)
12:43:35    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.Parser.process(Parser.java:80)
12:43:35    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.Parser.process(Parser.java:74)
12:43:35    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expand(TokenMacro.java:199)
12:43:35    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:237)
12:43:35    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:207)
12:43:35    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildnamesetter.Executor.evaluateMacro(Executor.java:75)
12:43:35    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildnamesetter.Executor.setName(Executor.java:30)
12:43:35    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildnamesetter.BuildNameSetter.setUp(BuildNameSetter.java:84)
12:43:35    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:157)
12:43:35    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
12:43:35    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
12:43:35    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
12:43:35    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
12:43:35    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)`
```

Is this an issue with latest Jenkins or with some plug-in?

Observations:

- This issue is NOT observed after downgrading to v2.207
- This issue is NOT seen with v2.211 and v2.210.

Comment: It seems to be something in v2.212. I just ran into this issue after upgrading from v2.210. I downgraded to v2.211 and the problem went away.

Comment: @MichaelRush: Thanks. I should have refreshed the page earlier :-) I didn't see the problem after downgrading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The changelog at https://jenkins.io/changelog/ has added a warning for 2.212 (2020-01-05):

> WARNING: This release introduces a critical regression, see JENKINS-60644. Please avoid updating to this version.

Answer (score 6):

Upgrade the plugin **Token Macro** to **2.15**

https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-name-setter-plugin/issues/60