# Jenkins v2.277.3: Error creating extended parser class: Class not found

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins v2.277.3 and based on one of the similar question, I also upgraded Token Macro plugin to v2.15.

[Jenkins v2.212: Error creating extended parser class: Class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618968/jenkins-v2-212-error-creating-extended-parser-class-class-not-found)

When running the job I have encountered the following issue.

```
 FATAL: Error creating extended parser class: null
 java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicInterpreter.<init>(BasicInterpreter.java:66)
    at org.parboiled.transform.RuleMethodInterpreter.<init>(RuleMethodInterpreter.java:42)
    at org.parboiled.transform.InstructionGraphCreator.process(InstructionGraphCreator.java:41)
    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.runMethodTransformers(ParserTransformer.java:62)
    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.extendParserClass(ParserTransformer.java:45)
    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.transformParser(ParserTransformer.java:39)
    at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:54)
 Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating extended parser class: null
    at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.Parser.process(Parser.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.Parser.process(Parser.java:74)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expand(TokenMacro.java:199)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:237)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:207)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildnamesetter.Executor.evaluateMacro(Executor.java:75)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildnamesetter.Executor.setName(Executor.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildnamesetter.BuildNameSetter.setUp(BuildNameSetter.java:84)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:157)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:513)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downgrading to v2.12 of the Token Macro plugin and installing v2.15 again. The problem occurred after I upgraded a bunch of plugins at once. I have Jenkins 2.289.1. This was my stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicInterpreter.<init>(BasicInterpreter.java:66)
    at org.parboiled.transform.RuleMethodInterpreter.<init>(RuleMethodInterpreter.java:42)
    at org.parboiled.transform.InstructionGraphCreator.process(InstructionGraphCreator.java:41)
    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.runMethodTransformers(ParserTransformer.java:62)
    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.extendParserClass(ParserTransformer.java:45)
    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.transformParser(ParserTransformer.java:39)
    at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:54)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating extended parser class: null
    at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.Parser.process(Parser.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.Parser.process(Parser.java:74)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expand(TokenMacro.java:199)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:237)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:207)
    at jenkins.plugins.office365connector.FactsBuilder.evaluateMacro(FactsBuilder.java:134)
    at jenkins.plugins.office365connector.FactsBuilder.addUserFacts(FactsBuilder.java:125)
    at jenkins.plugins.office365connector.CardBuilder.createBuildMessageCard(CardBuilder.java:183)
    at jenkins.plugins.office365connector.Office365ConnectorWebhookNotifier.sendBuildStepNotification(Office365ConnectorWebhookNotifier.java:100)
    at jenkins.plugins.office365connector.workflow.Execution.run(Execution.java:33)
    at jenkins.plugins.office365connector.workflow.Execution.run(Execution.java:15)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```